# Crash when deleting CStringArray*

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I'm noob in C++ world and I'm facing a weird behaviour. I use Visual Studio 2010.

The context: I decided to use wxWidget for GUI.

For this, I had to change in my project properties the following settings:

**C/C++** > **Code Generation** > **Runtime library** > **/MTd**  (previously it was /MDd)

**General** > **Use of MFC** > **Use MFC in a shared DLL** (previously it was Use MFC in a static library)

Since these changes, all my `delete[]` on `CStringArray*` crash my app. 
I try to change `delete[]` by `delete` but it causes a huge memory leak.

I don't understand why theses changes in project settings generate this difference of behaviour.

EDIT:

***The output message is:***

> HEAP[xxx.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 002B0000,
>   002BDE54 ) Windows has triggered a breakpoint in xxx.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in
>   xxx.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while xxx.exe has focus.

I have read [that](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148652):

> The CRT libraries use weak external linkage for the new, delete, and
>   DllMain functions. The MFC libraries also contain new, delete, and
>   DllMain functions. These functions require the MFC libraries to be
>   linked before the CRT library is linked.

So I tried to add in *Properties*> *Configuration Properties*> *Linker* > *Input* > *Ignore Specific Default libraries*: **nafxcwd.lib;libcmtd.lib;**

no changes.

In the call stack, I see that it's CStringArray::vector deleting destructor that is invoked.

Comment: Did you execute a "new" on the CStringArray to create it on the heap?

Comment: Yes, I do. In "/MDd mode", all work flawlessly, no memory leaks, no crash...

Comment: Where does the code crash? And, are you including [AFXDLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f20edzb(v=vs.100).aspx) in your build settings?

Comment: can you show us the code how you created `CStringArray*` with your new operator. I suspect it was created as a single object, that needs to be destroyed using `delete`, not `delete[]` as you are doing

Comment: `CStringArray* m_ArrayResult = new CStringArray();` I already tried to change `delete[]` by `delete` but it leads me to huge memory leaks... For the AFXDLL, how can I check if it's correctly included?

Comment: @Groco: if you create `CStringArray` that way, you allocate a single object. Destroying it with `delete[]` is incorrect.

Comment: I understand that, but `delete` doesn't work (memory leaks). In `/MDd` mode, I used `delete[]` and it works nice. Before using `delete[]`, I tried `delete` and it caused leaks.

Comment: do you really need to allocate CStringArray on the heap? normally you just have it as an auto member since it is a collection.

Comment: Yes, I need it, it's the returned value of a method I called several times. In fact, I don't want to change my code as it works in /MDd.

Comment: Check your project settings for AFXDLL.

Comment: What do I have to check?

Comment: You mention wxWidgets: Have you made sure you're putting `CString` instances into the CStringArray and not doing something funny to get `wxString` instances?

Comment: Sure, I mentionned wxWidget to explain why am I changing code generation settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I give up. I have left to much time on this problem. 
I think that there is an underlying issue that spread when I'm deleting a pointer.

I'm gonna try Qt...

Comment: You did not say where you new'ed the pointer and where you deleted it. That matters.
If you new'ed the pointer in an EXE and deleted it in a DLL, with /MT option yo uare dealing with different heaps